# Need help understanding going from one Arduino to another

Tags: arduino

The last microcontroller I used was an MSP430

Which used code like

```
WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // Stop watchdog timer
P2REN = 0;
P2DIR = 0;
P1DIR = (BIT0 | BIT1 | BIT2);// this sets up the output pin 1.0 1.1 1.2 to be able to be turned on
P2DIR |= (BIT0 | BIT1);// this allows the pin 2.0 and 2.1 to be able to be read from
```

I am now using STM32F103C8T6
or STM32 as most sites/videos call it.

I am looking for a means to when a sensor is tripped or "ON" to intercept that via a pin and output an action via another pin.

i.e. for

If (reads input pin)

(does action to output pin)

From what I can tell from all the research I have done the STM32 is more "complex" but "dumber" at the same time where before I could just read a pin and do an action it now seems very complex in what I have to do to do the same thing that was just a simple process before.

Any ideas or hints to point me in the right direction? If you can give me an example of how a code block sample would be laid out I learn best by reverse engineering examples and testing to see how it works.

Comment: your code doesn't look like arduino. why not use pinMode and digitalWrite/Read? that is the same on all arduinos

Comment: This should not be tagged as "arduino", it should be tagged as "[stm32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stm32)", which related to non-arduino STM32 programming.

Comment: we've decided to scrap the stm32 and move back to better products.  it was found it couldn't even be programmed without additional chip.  Not worth using at all.

Also thanks juraj for the pinMode and digitalwrite and read suggestion would have worked perfectly had the product not been useless.

Comment: Given the price of these chips and the embedded computation power in there I find that a bit rude ;). PIC also need additional chip for programming, that's the price to pay for small device. Furthermore, BluePill chips can be programmed using the USB port.